# range error in java using substring and index of

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract part of a string in java but i get an error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -23
```

code:

```
String searchLine = "feng shui";         
String str = "Feng shui (i pinyin: fēng shuǐ) is a Chinese philosophical system of harmonizing everyone with the surrounding environment. The term feng shui literally ...";

String pstr= str.substring(str.indexOf(searchLine)+1, str.indexOf("."));
```

I want the string from the position that it founds until the "."

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your `searchLine`?

Comment: we don't know what `strg` and `searchline` is and also I doubt that  that line caused exception since `indexOf` won't return -23

Comment: `"feng shui"` appears *after* `"."` in `str`, so the indices are in the wrong order.

Comment: how can i get only the first feng shui or any world in any form with upper case or lower case?

Answer (score 1):

As per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29, if the `endIndex` is before the `startIndex` you will get an exception.

In your case, the first `.` character in the string `str` is before the first `feng shui` (captialisation and exact character matches are significant), which causes an exception.

```
"Feng shui (i pinyin: fēng shuǐ) is a Chinese philosophical system of 
 harmonizing everyone with the surrounding environment. The term feng shui literally ..."; 
                                                      ^          ^
```

Comment: How can i get always only the first searchLine in any format?

Comment: Maybe using a regular expression, but I'm not certain about how that will handle the characters with accents.